# IIS not serving dynamic content until website restart

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server

We have the following setup:

- AWS auto scaling group for creating web servers for load balancing
- The image for our web servers have IIS and all required modules installed
- An ASP.NET MVC website that is automatically installed and deployed on a newly created web server

In about half of the launches of new web servers, the following problem occurs: all requests for dynamic content result in 404, for example the following line in the IIS access logs:

```
2018-02-21 16:50:11 xx.xx.xx.xx POST /XXXX/XXXX - 443 1516 xxx.xx.xx.xxx Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:58.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/58.0 - 404 0 2 14531
```

The browser displays a white screen. Static content comes back with 200 in our access logs.

The problem goes away when we restart the website, for example by modifying the web.config. Of course, the web site should work immediately, what could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Does this problem occur with browsers that do not have the old image file cached? If so, your problem might relate to the cache-control meta tags defined inside the head tags of the posted page.

Comment: Your question states that 404 errors occur for "about half of the launches of new web servers". Could the image file be defined on some servers being used but not on others?

Comment: @JohnH Just to clarify, with "image", I mean an image with pre-installed windows and IIS, not an actual image file. All web servers are identical because they use the same image.

Comment: The posted 404 log display is truncated. What web object was referenced in the log for that 404 (Not Found) Http status code? In addition to checking the web log files, the Chrome browser's Inspect function can also show this information using the "Network" tab.